# click event ng-click not working

Tags: ionic-framework

History and Home page are work fine but 'ng-click="toggleMenu()"' are not working so please help me
click event `ng-click="toggleMenu()"`is not working..

can anyone help me to solve it?

My code is,

```
<ion-tab title="History" icon-off="ion-document" icon-on="ion-document-text" href="#/tab/history">
<ion-nav-view name="tab-history"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab> 
<a class="button"  ng-click="toggleMenu()">More</a>
```

```
.controller('MoreCtrl', function($scope,$ionicSideMenuDelegate) {

$scope.toggleMenu = function()
{
    alert('test toggle');
    $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleRight();
};

})
```

Comment: please provide your  MFP version ? error? ionic version ?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25422584/angularjs-ng-click-not-working

Comment: The problem here is with Angular and not with any feature provided by MFP. Do not add the mobilefirst tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think controller are not required here . can you try this way.

```
 <ion-tab title="More" icon-off="ion-ios-more-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-more" ng-click="toggleMenu()"> 
                             </ion-tab> 
                          </ion-tabs>
        .run(function($ionicPlatform,$state,$rootScope,$ionicActionSheet,$ionicSideMenuDelegate) {

            $rootScope.toggleMenu = function() {

                alert('test toggle');
                $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleRight();
            }
        })
```

check this question please [Ionic framework ion tabs not firing event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26131149/ionic-framework-ion-tabs-not-firing-event?rq=1)

more information this link for demo
http://codepen.io/cfjedimaster/pen/iplCx

Comment: What is  you thinking about this  problem , here is with Angular and not  related mobilefirst.

Comment: yeah. It is Angular js. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please add your full html code. Have you correctly attached `MoreCtrl` to the DOM? Is your DOM in line with [Ionic guidelines](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicSideMenuDelegate/) for `$ionicSideMenuDelegate`? I don't see the `<ion-side-menus>` tag for example, like below:

```
<body ng-controller="MoreCtrl">
  <ion-side-menus>
    <ion-side-menu-content>
      Content!
      <button ng-click="toggleRightSideMenu()">
        Toggle Right Side Menu
      </button>
    </ion-side-menu-content>
  </ion-side-menus>
</body>
```